# $_GET not working with .htaccess rewrite remove php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

The following url:

https://example.com/rewards.php&id=307658063902 (does not get the ID with GET)

OR

https://example.com/rewards&id=307658063902 (returns error not found)

Does not work with retrieving the GET variable ID with php:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

I think there may be a mistake in my .htaccess file, which is:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Replace & with ?.. If you are sending parameter, should be written after '?'. like this https://example.com/rewards.php?id=307658063902

Comment: That was it, I am an idiot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed ? in your URL,try the below example and check:

```
https://example.com/rewards.php?id=307658063902
$id = $_GET["id"];
echo $id;
```

Sample Output:

```
307658063902
```